# Trying to send email in Angular 6 using Sendgrid with Cloud functions endpoint

Tags: angular, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

Hello I'm trying to send an email from an angular cloud function using SendGrid.

Following this example : https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sendgrid-v3-nodejs-transactional-email-cloud-function/

I have written the following functio

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const SENDGRID_API_KEY="*******************************";
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
exports.httpEmail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

cors( req, res, () => { 

    const toName  = req.body.toName;
    const toEmail = req.body.toEmail;

    const msg = {
        to: toEmail,
        from: 'glkjrzklegklre@gmail.com',
        subject:  'New Message',
        text: `You have a new message`,
        html: `You have a new message`,
    };

    return sgMail.send(msg)

        .then(() => res.status(200).send('email sent!') )
        .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err) )

});});
```

And I'm simply calling it from a component :

```
sendEmail() {
const data = {
  toEmail: 'cbanzet@gmail.com',
  toName: 'Jeff Delaney'
}
this.http.post(this.endpoint, data).subscribe()}
```

Even though it's written "Email Sent!" in the console, I have to following error :

error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

I don't know what to do with this and I would really like to make it work.

Comment: That's because the response is expected to be JSON, but it's actually sending `email sent!` which is not valid JSON. You can change it to something like `{"message": "email sent!"}` instead which should work

Comment: yes the error is gone with {"message": "email sent!"}... thanks for your help. Still need to find a way for the emails not to fall into spam folder...